# How to add space between elements (but not outside of them) using CSS?

Tags: css, iframe, margins

I have a set of iFrames, actually social sharing buttons from Facebook, Google, etc., and I want to put space in between them using CSS, while not adding space before the first iFrame or after the last one.  Is there some way to accomplish a "margin-inner" sort of effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a global margin and simply reset the last one (or first one)

```
iframe {
    margin-left:20px;
}
iframe:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Comment: Actually you should use `margin-left` & `first-child` pseudoselector because there are more browser supporting this.

Comment: Good call lonut. Didn't realize `:first-child` was CSS2 and `:last-child` was CSS3. The only browser affected by the swap is IE8